# Не могу установить Mail_Mime

Tags: linux, centos

У меня есть готовый скрип, написанные не мной, я его запустил, но в ходе его выполнения появились строка:

> no releases available for package pear.php.net/Mail_Mime

Я попытался вручную установить его, написал вот так:

```
# pear install Mail_Mime
```

Но получил такую-же строку...

UPD: pear install Net_SMTP, тоже не работает, похожая строка вместо установки вылазит

UPD: прилагаю скрин пробелмы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я совсем новенький в линукс, помогите пожалуйста. Какую информацию нужно предоставить для решения моей проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `# git clone https://github.com/pear/Mail_Mime` прописать в консоль если хочешь установить